# Drop down list doesnt show the selected value in edit mode in mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view, viewdata, html.dropdownlistfor

Hi I am trying to display the database value on the dropdownlist in the edit section, but the drop down list shows the default set value below is my code:
Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
       // Product helmet = new Product();//
        //Product garrage = new Product();

        ViewBag.mode = "edit";
        // for dropdown track
        ITrackRepository trackResp = new TrackRepository();
        IQueryable<Object> tracks = trackResp.GetVenuesSelectlist();
        ViewData["Venue"] = new SelectList(tracks, "VenueID", "Name");

        // for dropdown for event type
        ITrackdayRepository trackdayResp = new TrackdayRepository();
        IQueryable<EventType> eventTypes = trackdayResp.GetAllEventTypes();
        ViewData["EventTypes"] = new SelectList(eventTypes, "ID", "Name");

        // for dropdown experience
        IExperienceLevelRepository expLevelResp = new ExperienceLevelRepository();
        IQueryable<ExperienceLevel> expLevel = expLevelResp.GetAllExperienceLevels().OrderBy(ExperienceLevel => ExperienceLevel.Name);
        ViewData["Experience"] = new SelectList(expLevel, "ID", "Name");

        // dropdown for helmets
        IProductRepository prodResp = new ProductRepository();
        Product productQuantity = prodResp.GetProd(id);

        if (productQuantity.ProductTypeID == 1)
        {
            // dropdown for attendees
            var attendees = Enumerable.Range(1, 80).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
            ViewData["attendees1"] = new SelectList(attendees, "Value", "Text",**productQuantity.QtyAvailable)**; //productQuantity.QtyAvailable is the value from db(selected value of dropdown)

            ViewData["txtAttendees"] = productQuantity.UnitCost;
        }


        else
        {
            var emptyattendees = Enumerable.Range(1, 80).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
            ViewData["attendees1"] = new SelectList(emptyattendees.ToList(), "Value", "Text");


        }    Event trackday = trackdayResp.GetEvent(id); //returns all the values from event table whose eventid is id

        //need to return product quantity, value to drop downlist
       return View("Create", trackday);

    }
```

View Edited(WOrking):

```
  <% if (ViewBag.mode != "edit")
                  { %>

                <%: Html.DropDownList("attendees1", ViewData["attendees1"] as SelectList, "--select--")%>
               <%}else{%>
               <%: Html.DropDownList("attendees1")%>
               <%} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a month ago, and I solved it by doing this:

```
ViewData["attendees1"] = new SelectList(attendees, "Value", "Text", productQuantity.QtyAvailable);
```

I mean, you have to add a 4th parameter with the SelectedValue which you take it from the original value before the edit. You have to do this only in Edit action, no need to do that in Create since it is a new object and no value is selected yet.

And in your markup you define the DropDownList like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("attendees1") %>
```

This way the selected value will be selected instead of the default one.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**
Create action method:

```
ViewData["attendees1"] = new SelectList(attendees, "Value", "Text");
```

Edit action method:

```
ViewData["attendees1"] = new SelectList(attendees, "Value", "Text", productQuantity.QtyAvailable);
```

Markup in both Create and Edit views

```
<%: Html.DropDownList("attendees1") %>
```

Comment: thnx for your reply , but if i remove this then i cant display in the create section coz i m using same for both ..create and edit

Comment: edited code works fine thnx for ur suggestions.. Althought it doesnt answer the question but provided me with a thought which solve my issue ... :)

Comment: @Awais do consider using strongly typed helpers

Comment: well i m in the middle of everything so cant move to custom type model view , but surely in d next project will work with strongly type as it make life easier .. playing with view data is killing me nd making it more complex now i m stuck in update of edit:)